# how to concatenate a string in controller side to autofill form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap form where user enter an email I want if user doesn't enter @scoops.com it concatenates automatically either form side or controller side

In controller it saves using this `$customer->email = $request->email;` if want to check at controller side how I can check if user enters @scoops.com at the end of user name. If it is missing then concatenate @scoops.com with user name

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email <span style="opacity: 0.5; font-style: italic; color: red;">(Required)</span></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Email" name="name" required="@scoops.com" / onfocus='tmp=this.value;this.value=""' onblur='if(this.value=="")this.value=tmp'>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">@scoops.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="suggested-emails" class="list-group"></ul>
  <span id="error_email"></span> 
  @if($errors->has('email'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    </div>
  @endif
</div>

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$customer->email = $request->email;

if (!preg_match('/^.*@scoops.com$/', $customer->email)) {
  $customer->email .= '@scoops.com';
}
```

The risk is if they put in anything@example.com, you'll then get anything@example.com@scoops.com.  It probably needs something additional to check if it looks like an email address already (i.e. has at least an "@" in it).

Comment: thanx for your help you are right so in case we should have fornt end validation using javascript i think

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will check if **@scoop.com** is present or not like below:

```
   use Illuminate\Support\Str;

   $myString = '@scoop.com';
   $contains = Str::contains($request->email, '@scoop.com');
```

**$contains** will either true or false

if it's false then concatenate **@scoop.com** as below

```
$newString = $request->email.$myString;
```

Comment: this answer don't have any limitations though. i have tried it.